# Probabilities of four statistically dependent discrete variable

Tags: probability

Let $A_0,A_1,B_0,B_1$ be random variables with a joint probability mass function, each of whom may get $1$ or $-1$. I have a few questions concerning them:

1. Bell's inequality, here I have to show that:
   $|E[A_0B_0]+E[A_0B_1]+E[A_1B_0]-E[A_1B_1]|\le 2$
   Would this substitute as a sufficient proof:
   $|E[A_0B_0]+E[A_0B_1]+E[A_1B_0]-E[A_1B_1]=|E[A_0(B_0+B_1)]+E[A_1(B_1-B_0)]|\le {(using \ triangle \ inequality)}\le |E[A_0(B_0+B_1)]|+|E[A_1(B_1-B_0)]|=???$
   Now, if $P(B_0=1)=P(B_1=1)=1$, then $???=2$, else if $P(B_0=1)=P(B_1=-1)$, then also $???=2$. Where the probabilities of $A_0,A_1$ are uninteresting because $|E[A_i]|=1$.
2. Next, one needs to show how $P(A_cB_d=(-1)^{cd})={1\over2}(1+(-1)^{cd}E[A_cB_d])$, where $c,d$ are indices which may take $0,1$. Again, as I understand, nothing can be inferred of the expectation value.
3. One runs a trial with $A_c$ and $B_d$, assuming the probability of choosing each pair is $1/4$, what is the highest probability that in that trial run one gets $(1,-1)$ or $(-1,1)$ iff $c=d=1$, and $(1,1)$ or $(-1,-1)$ only when $c$ or $d$ equals $0$.
4. Let $Z_{00},Z_{01},Z_{10},Z_{00}$ be four random variables which get $1$ or $-1$. Show that $E[Z_{00}Z_{10}]=E[Z_{01}Z_{11}]$ iff $Z_{ab}=X_aY_b$, where $X_A$ and $Y_b$ which may get $1$ or $-1$. I have only one direction:
   $E[Z_{00}Z_{10}]=E[x_0y_0x_1y_0]=E[x_0x_1{y_0}^2]=E[x_0x_1]$
   and
   $E[Z_{01}Z_{11}]=E[x_0y_1x_1y_1]=E[x_0x_1{y_1}^2]=E[x_0x_1]$
5. Assuming $E[Z_{00}Z_{10}]=E[Z_{01}Z_{11}]$, prove that when one discards the axiom that probability is a non-negative number then the inequality $|E[A_0B_0]+E[A_0B_1]+E[A_1B_0]-E[A_1B_1]|\le 2$ may be broken.

Thank you, whoever tries to help me! 
Any answer might help me, even if only for one of the items.

Comment: Coin tosses are independent.

Comment: maybe calling them coin tosses is problematic, i'll fix that

Comment: Is there a difference between the $A$ and $B$ variables?

Comment: They stand for the results of different coins, physically I know that they should be uncorrelated, but for the sake of this problem I can't assume that

Comment: Why mention coins at all?  Just call them variables.  Do you want each to be $1,-1$ with probability $\frac 12$?  If so, just say that.

Comment: Alright, just wanted to stay loyal to the original (but very confusing) version. I'll edit that

Comment: I don't understand question $2$.  Suppose all the variables are equal.  Then  $A_cB_d=1$ for all pairs $c,d$ and $E[A_cB_d]=1$ as well.  But your formula has a non-trivial dependence on $c,d$.

Comment: But why suppose all variables are equal?

Comment: Because it gives a counterexample to your formula.  That means  (unless I botched it) that your formula can not be true for all dependence structures.

Comment: I don't agree, suppose $A_0=A_1=B_0=B_1=1$, then $P(A_0B_0=1)=1, P(A_0B_1=1)=1, P(A_1B_0=1)=1, P(A_1B_1=-1)=0$

Comment: I think this question should be clarified.  Maybe broken into more than one post (the bit with all the $Z's$ seems unrelated to what comes before).  State your assumptions clearly.  If you want each variable to be $\pm 1$ with equal probability, say so.  (I'm only guessing you want that because you called them coin tosses).  Why are some called $A$ and others called $B$?  Is that irrelevant or is there some meaning?

Comment: The problem is that's the clearest I can get, this is what I know of these variables... I don't want them to be $\pm1$ with equal probability because I wasn't given that data... But I thank you for your help!
I'm guessing they are called that way because each letter doesn't multiply itself. The $Z$'s are really from a different question but with the same beginning (item 1)

Comment: I think you are right about my example.  That is, I think I misread your formula and that it might be correct so I withdraw my comment about the counterexample.

Comment: Indeed: to prove $2$ let us pick a pair $c,d$ and declare that $(A_c,B_d)$ is $(1,1)$ with prob $p_1$, $(1,-1)$ with prob $p_2$, $(-1,1)$ with prob $p_3$ and $(-1,-1)$ with prob $p_4$. (Note: $p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4=1$) Then $P(A_cB_d=1)$ is $p_1+p_4$.  The expectation is $p_1+p_4 -p_2-p_3$  so if $cd$ is even then you are asking that $p_1+p_4=\frac 12\times (1+p_1+p_4-p_2-p_3)$ which is true, and similarly if $cd$ is odd.

Comment: Great, thanks! quite simple actually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1. Let's calculate the expression $A_0B_0+A_0B_1+A_1B_0-A_1B_1$:

$$A_0B_0+A_0B_1+A_1B_0-A_1B_1=A_0(B_0+B_1)+A_1(B_0-B_1)$$

Now we have 2 cases: either $B_0=B_1$ or $B_0=-B_1$

In the 1st case we get $2A_0B_0$, in the 2nd case we get $2A_1B_0$. In both cases

$$A_0B_0+A_0B_1+A_1B_0-A_1B_1=\pm2$$

and it follows from here that

$$-2\leqslant E[A_0B_0+A_0B_1+A_1B_0-A_1B_1]\leqslant 2$$

Comment: Thanks, I understand my answer is in agreement with yours, where yours is probably more precise?

Comment: @GabyFleurov You are wrong in things like $P(B_0=1)=P(B_1=1)=1$ - you need actual values of random variables, not the probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Part 2.

$A_cB_d$ can assume values $1$ and $-1$.

Consider first the case that $c=1$ and $d=1$. Then,
$$P(A_1B_1 = 1) + P(A_1B_1 = -1) = 1$$
$$E[A_1B_1] = 1 \cdot P(A_1B_1 = 1) + (-1) \cdot  P(A_1B_1 = -1)$$
$$E[A_1B_1] = 1 - P(A_1B_1 = -1) - P(A_1B_1 = -1)$$
which implies,
$$P(A_1B_1 = -1) = \frac{1}{2}\bigg(1 - E[A_1B_1]\bigg)$$

Now consider (without loss of generality) $c=0$ and $d=1$.
$$P(A_0B_1 = 1) + P(A_0B_1 = -1) = 1$$
$$E[A_0B_1] = 1 \cdot P(A_0B_1 = 1) + (-1) \cdot  P(A_0B_1 = -1)$$
$$E[A_0B_1] = P(A_0B_1 = 1) - (1 - P(A_0B_1 = 1))$$
which implies,
$$P(A_0B_1 = 1) = \frac{1}{2}\bigg(1 + E[A_0B_1]\bigg)$$

The case is similar for $c=0, \ d=0$ and $c=1, \ d=0$

This has been generalized in 2 as $P\bigg(A_cB_d = (-1)^{cd}\bigg) = \frac{1}{2}\bigg(1 + (-1)^{cd}E[A_cB_d]\bigg)$